# Detect when "settings" command in terminal has finished saving

Tags: settings, terminal

When I execute the following command, it doesn't save anything:

```
settings put global <KEY> <VALUE>;reboot
```

I think it's because it does not have enough time to save the value, because it reboots. The following command does save the value:

```
settings put global <KEY> <VALUE>;sleep 1;reboot
```

Is there any better way to wait until the command has saved the value?

Comment: On trying `settings put global KEY VALUE; settings get global KEY` commands on my OPO, the `get` command returns the edited value.The changes are even reflected in the Settings app. I'm not sure why the value isn't being saved before the reboot. If this doesn't work for you, I don't see a better way to hack the problem.

Comment: @EvilTak That actually did work for me. I think the "settings get" command waits for it to finish, so this will work: `settings put global enable_freeform_support 1; settings get global enable_freeform_support; reboot`.

Comment: You may want to try `settings put <NAMESPACE> <KEY> <VALUE> && reboot`. It worked for me, with the value `screen_brightness` under the `system` namespace.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman That didn't work for me. See my previous comment for a solution.